# How can I change image.source with C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.I have an image . This is its XAML code:

```
<Image x:Name="imageclock" Grid.Row="1" 
        Source="Image/Myimage.png" Height="240" Width="240"
        />
```

And i want change image.source with this code:

```
private void ClickonBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Image/Darktheme.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            imageclock.Source = bm;
    }
```

But when i complied, imageclock.Source=Null and this is error:

> *An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Newappver1.DLL but was not handled in user code*

Comment: And you verified that in the `Image` directory there is a file named `Darktheme.png`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks ok but maybe you need to add `@` before the image path to handle the `/` in the code behind like this :

```
BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Image/Darktheme.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: You usually need to prepend a string with `@` to preserve special characters (or you can escape them with backslash) but `/` is not one of them so you shouldn't need to escape it/use `@`

Answer (score 0):

```
imageclock.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Image/Darktheme.png"));
```

source https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx